# outputting a buffer stream

Tags: boost, tcp, buffer, cout

I am simiply trying to display a message I receive from a tcp socket which terminates with "\r\n\r\n".

C++ however terminates immediately even though the server indicates that the message has been successfully transmitted.

```
        void handle_read( const boost::system::error_code& error, size_t bytes_transferred)
{
    std::istream response_stream(&response_);
    std::string incoming;
    std::string res_time = make_daytime_string();
    while (std::getline(response_stream, incoming) && incoming != "\r")
         std::cout << incoming << std::endl;
    std::cout <<"message received on "<< res_time <<std::endl;
}
```

In Eclipse I see the following in consol,
(exit value = -1)
When the program is terminated, If I switch to the consol of Linux I see the following error:
*** Error in `/home/administrator/Documents/eclipse/Projects/Asynchronous_TCP/Debug/Asynchronous_TCP': double free or corruption (!prev): 0x0000000001040580 ***

Comment: It's quite possible that if you run this on a single threaded io_service, it fails because you're in the completion handler (and hence you're blocking the event loop).
If you make it a SSCCE we could verify it. And possibly suggest a fix

Answer (score 0):

Solved
Apperantly I only needed to resolved the socket connection